# Select Evenly Spaced Rows Between 2 timestamptz

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select N rows between 2 timestamptz columns and have them be spaced out evenly. I'm logging temperature and humidity every 5 seconds and I want to create a chart using chartjs for a time period(say last 24 hours)

My table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temperatures
(
    id          BIGSERIAL   PRIMARY KEY,
    timestamp   TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    temp_f      REAL        NOT NULL,
    humidity    REAL        NOT NULL
);
```

In English the query would read:
`SELECT 24 evenly spaced rows FROM temperatures table WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2022-04-20 00:00:00' AND '2022-04-21 00:00:00' with the first and last rows as close to specified times as possible`

This would return something like:

```
 timestamp            |  temp_f   | humidity
-------------------------------+-----------+
 2022-04-20 00:00:05  |      70.7 |     54.2
 2022-04-20 01:00:03  |     72.32 |     53.9
 ...
 ...
 2022-04-20 23:59:59  |     72.32 |     53.4
...
```

From my own searching it seems like generate_series might work, but I cannot figure out how to map the generated series to my table.

Here is a dbfiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8vakciTyFvb5PQniwuwanQ/0

Answer (score 0):

In English what parameter will make rows even? Are they separated by time, number of rows, value of some column, or something else? What is your denominator to space out rows?

Comment: I plan on having a few graphs and would like to be able to select a period(say 24 hours) and a resolution(say 1 hour) so the query would return 24 rows with each row's timestamp 1 hour apart. So it's basically the period divided by the resolution. A 5 hour period with a resolution of 5 would return 5 rows. Each row would consist of the timestamp, temp_f, and humidity.